# Wrong output when popping from the stack

Tags: c, structure, stack

I have made a program using stacks, but the output which i get is kind of wrong. The output i get, has the answer i need and also has 2 values which are not expected.

Here is what i have done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#define MAX 180

struct cakes{
    int spongecake;
    int meringue;
    int chocalate;
    int red_velvet;
    struct cakes *next;
};

struct stack{
    int top;
    int cake[10];
};

int isFull(struct stack *);
int isEmpty(struct stack *);
void push(struct stack *,int);
int pop(struct stack *);

void order_out(struct cakes *);

main()
{
    struct cakes *head;

    head=(struct cakes *)malloc(sizeof(struct cakes));
    cake_order(head); //this is a seperate function, it works perfectly.
    head->next=(struct cakes *)malloc(sizeof(struct cakes));
    order_out(head->next);
}

int isFull(struct stack *q)
{ 
    if(q->top==10-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void push(struct stack *sptr,int x)
{
    if(!isFull(sptr))
    {
        sptr->top++;
        sptr->cake[sptr->top]=x;
    }
}   

int isEmpty(struct stack *q)
{
    if(q->top==-1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}

int pop(struct stack *sptr)
{
    int ret=NULL;
    if(!isEmpty(sptr))
    {
        ret=sptr->cake[sptr->top];
        sptr->top--;
        return ret;
    }
}

void order_out(struct cakes *theorder)
{
    struct stack s;
    s.top=-1;
    int k=0;
    int i=0;
    int p=0;
    int r=0;    
    int value1,value2;
    int items[10];    

    theorder->spongecake=1;
    theorder->meringue=2;
    theorder->chocalate=3;
    theorder->red_velvet=4;

    for(;i<10;i++)
    {
        push(&s,theorder->spongecake);

        push(&s,theorder->meringue);
        push(&s,theorder->chocalate);
        push(&s,theorder->red_velvet);
    }

    while(!isEmpty(&s))
    {
        printf("\n%d",pop(&s));
    }
}
```

The output which I get is as follows : 
[image]

As you can see it prints 2 and 1 first. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: `pop()` returns an unspecified value if (!isEmpty(sptr)) == FALSE

Comment: Sorry i don't get what you are trying to say. Can you please explain a bit. Thank you.

Comment: can u specify from where the output of order_out() starts

Comment: Well it starts from the top and the top gradually decreases as the values are removed.

Comment: where's the function by name cake_order ?

Comment: Well i didn't include that part because it doesn't have anything to do with  this scenario.

Comment: no what i actually meant was - from where in the output screen does the order_out() starts printing?

Comment: from the value 2 it starts popping from the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion your program is working as follows,

The following loop tries to insert 40 values,

```
for(;i<10;i++)
{
   push(&s,theorder->spongecake);
   push(&s,theorder->meringue);
   push(&s,theorder->chocalate);
   push(&s,theorder->red_velvet);
}
```

But only 10 values are inserted because of your statement `if(q->top==10-1)` in your `isFull()` function. i.e the counter counts 10 elements from 0 to 9. The order in which the elements are pushed is as follows `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2`. These elements when popped gives you the sequence `2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1`. Thus the output you obtain is actually correct or at least not an aberration.

There are a few more issues I would like to point out,

The function `pop()` should be as follows,

```
 int pop(struct stack *sptr)
 {
    int ret=NULL;
    if(!isEmpty(sptr))
    {
        ret=sptr->cake[sptr->top];
        sptr->top--;
        return ret;
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Otherwise the function returns random values when `sptr` is empty.

The statement `if(q->top==10-1)` should be `if(q->top==9)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with stack except the pop implementation where return value NULL is returned when stack is empty. Better return an invalid number as convention(like 0, -1, -999) left to your choice.

As you are restricting the stack size to 10, only 10 values are being inserted. So while inserting only following are inserted 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 and are popped inorder.